# Getting a 'Cannot read property 'on' of undefined' when calling a function in a class in a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules

Here's my code:

From the module's index.js:

```
class TSL5 extends EventEmitter {
    constructor () {
        super()
        //Message Format
        this._PBC     = 0 //offset
        this._VER     = 2
        this._FLAGS   = 3
        this._SCREEN  = 4
        this._INDEX   = 6
        this._CONTROL = 8
        this._LENGTH  = 10
    }

    listenUDP(port) {
        this.server = dgram.createSocket('udp4')
        this.server.bind(port)

        this.server.on('message',(msg, rinfo) => {
            this.processTally(msg,rinfo)
            debug('Message recieved: ', msg)
        })

        this.server.on('listening', () => {
            var address = this.server.address();
            debug(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
        });

        this.server.on('error', (err) => {
            debug('server error: ', err);
            throw err;
        });

        return this.server;
    }
    processTally(data,rinfo) {
        let buf = Buffer.from(data)
        let tally = { display: {} }

        tally.sender  = rinfo.address
        tally.pbc     = buf.readInt16LE(this._PBC)
        tally.ver     = buf.readInt8(this._VER)
        tally.flags   = buf.readInt8(this._VER)
        tally.screen  = buf.readInt16LE(this._SCREEN)
        tally.index   = buf.readInt16LE(this._INDEX)
        tally.control = buf.readInt16LE(this._CONTROL)
        tally.length  = buf.readInt16LE(this._LENGTH)
        tally.display.text = buf.toString('ascii', this._LENGTH+2)

        tally.display.rh_tally     = (tally.control >> 0 & 0b11);
        tally.display.text_tally   = (tally.control >> 2 & 0b11);
        tally.display.lh_tally     = (tally.control >> 4 & 0b11);
        tally.display.brightness   = (tally.control >> 6 & 0b11);
        tally.display.reserved     = (tally.control >> 8 & 0b1111111);
        tally.display.control_data = (tally.control >> 15 & 0b1);

        this.emit('message',tally)
    }
```

and then the server side index.js:

```
let umd = new TSL5;

        for (let i = 0; i < source_connections.length; i++) {
            if (source_connections[i].sourceId === sourceId) {
                AddPort(port, sourceId);
                logger(`Source: ${source.name}  Creating TSL 5.0 UDP Connection.`, 'info-quiet');
                //source_connections[i].server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
                //source_connections[i].server.bind(port);
                source_connections[i].server = umd.listenUDP(port);
                source_connections[i].server.on('message', function (message) {
                    processTSL5Tally(sourceId, message);
                });

                logger(`Source: ${source.name}  TSL 5.0 Server started. Listening for data on UDP Port: ${port}`, 'info');
                for (let j = 0; j < sources.length; j++) {
                    if (sources[j].id === sourceId) {
                        sources[j].connected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                UpdateSockets('sources');
                UpdateCloud('sources');
                break;
            }
        }
```

Whenever I try to call the function that the lower block of code is in, then I get the `Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` error. The only way to get the error to go away is add a `return this.server` to the `listenUDP` function. If I do this however, then all of the data that function is supposed to emit through the `processTally` function is lost.

Comment: Which exact line of code is causing the error? You are calling `.on()` in several places.

Answer (score 1):

Your current issue is caused by those lines:

```js
source_connections[i].server = umd.listenUDP(port);
source_connections[i].server.on('message', function (message) {
  processTSL5Tally(sourceId, message);
});
```

`source_connections[i].server` is the result of calling `listenUDP`. Therefore if you **do not** return the server (through `return this.server`), then there's nothing to call `.on` upon.

And returning the server is causing another issue that you have:

```js
// in processTally
this.emit('message',tally)
```

But inside your loop, you're calling

```js
source_connections[i].server.on('message', function (message) {
```

The **event emitter** itself is emitting this new "message", but you are still listening on the "event emitter's server". The emitter (TSL5 class) is a wrapper over the server. So instead of listening on the server's message, you should listen on the event emitter, that emits "message" as well, that is the result of working on the internal server's message:

```js
// just the emitter, not the server
source_connections[i].on('message', function (message) {
  processTSL5Tally(sourceId, message);
});
```

---

As a side note - just remember you're having a single instance for the emitter. Therefore if that loops runs multiple times (for different connections), things will get scrambled. Therefore you'd probably need to create new emitter for each iteration, but not sure if that's your case.